# Recoger datos de tres inputs con el mismo name con puro PHP

Tags: php

Hola quisiera que me ayudaran soy principiante en esto de la programación y tengo que hacer un formulario de ventas con conexion a base de datos ,pero en mi formulario se pide el articulo , la cantidad y el precio; en cada uno de esos requerimientos se ponen tres inputs pero con el mismo name y quisiera saber como le puedo hacer para recoger los datos ingresados de cada inputs , ya que al imprimir los datos solo me manda el de un solo input.
espero puedan ayudarme y gracias.

Comment: Bueno es que desde ahi ya va un error, ¿por qué el mismo name?, si cada uno de los inputs esta destinado a un valor único, entonces lo que debes hacer es darles un name distinto y eso facilitará tu trabajo

Answer (score 3):

Por obligación cada input debe tener un `name` único que lo identifica, a menos que estén en formato **array**, como lo siguiente:

HTML

```
...
<input type="text" name="in_name[]" placeholder="Articulo" required>
<input type="text" name="in_name[]" placeholder="Cantidad" required>
<input type="text" name="in_name[]" placeholder="Precio" required>
...
```

PHP

```
<?php
$inputs = $_POST['in_name'];
var_dump($inputs); 
// Articulo: $inputs[0] | Cantidad: $inputs[1] | Precio: $inputs[2]
```

De otra manera no sería posible.